# Preloader animation not working

Tags: actionscript-3, class, preloader

I was making a preloader for my game I exported my movieclips to the frame 2 except those which are related to the preloader graphics In my Frame 1 i have this code

```
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
stop();
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , onProgress);
function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    progbar.width = (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) * 398;
    jot.x = progbar.x + progbar.width;     //jot is the name of loader label it moves with the
    jot.y = progbar.y;                     //end point of progbar
    jot.loadtext.text = String(Math.round(progbar.width / 398 * 100)) + " %"; // labale has text inside it
    if (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

and At the point where the bar has reach at any given time I wanted to put a bubbling effect for which i amde a class **Spark** 
this is how my spark class looks like

```
public class Spark extends MovieClip
    {

        private var pl:Array = new Array();
        private var t:int = 0;
        public function Spark()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnter);
        }
        private var l:int = 0;
        private var i:int = 0;
        private function onEnter(e:Event)
        {
            t++;
            if (t == 2)
            {
                t = 0;
                var p:P = new P();   // P is the single particle
                addChild(p);
                pl.push(p);         // pl is the array to hold particles
                p.width = Math.random() * 20 + 5;
                p.height = p.width;
                p.vx = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
                p.vy = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
            }
            l = pl.length;         //storing length of array to save performance
            for (i=0; i< l; i++)      
            {
                pl[i].alpha -=  0.05;
                pl[i].y +=  pl[i].vy;
                pl[i].x +=  pl[i].vx;
            }
            //removeing completely transparent particles
            for (i=0; i< l; i++)
            {
                if (pl[i].alpha < 0.02)
                {
                    removeChild(pl[i]);
                    pl.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in the first frame Spark Instance to the stage and added code for its alignment with the progbar
but nothing happened only the bar was going but bubbles were not coming out from its end.
I tried checking and unchecking the spark class "export in frame 2"

I hav named the dragged instance of class Spark as spark1
and when i added this code to frame 1 i am surpirised

```
if(spark1 != null)
{
   trace("its fine");
} else {
  trace("something weird");
}
```

and i got the else statement being traced out. How is that possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

1. I went to   File > Action-script setting.
2. there int the text field named as export classes in frame ___ .I put there 1 which i was previously having 2
3. Then unchecked **Export to frame 1** FOR ONLY THOSE SYMBOLS WHICH WERE PART OF THE PRELOADER

then ran the movie it worked